# How to use combineFileInputFormat for java in hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop

I am working with large number of small files and have used combineFileInputFormat to avoid having a lot of map tasks. it is working properly but the problem is that i need to have the id of each file, in this way all of file's id is 1. how can i keep the ids of files?do i have to add some code to my combineFileInputFormat?

Comment: Do you want to be able to find out the filename of where each Map input has come from?

Comment: @ChrisWhite for example i have 100 files and i need their name. but when i use CombineInputFormat, i can't get the file names.

Answer (score 0):

The `CombineFileRecordReader` configures a configuration property for the current file it is processing, so you should be able to obtain the current file name from the `map.input.file` property:

```
@Override
protected void map(Longwritable key, Text value, Context context) {
    String filePath = context.getConfiguration().get("map.input.file");
}
```

If you're using the old API (mapred), the property name is the same.

Comment: Thanks but i want to have my file's names in my Map function.can i access the method you mentioned from map? or i can do it in Map?