# Using CombineFileInputFormat for images (or BLOBs)?

Tags: image-processing, hadoop, mapreduce, blob

I planning a hdfs system that will host image files (few Mb to 200mb) for a digital repository (Fedora Commons). I found from [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730754/how-to-use-combinefileinputformat-for-java-in-hadoop) that CombineFileInputFormat can be used to create input splits consisting of multiple input files. Can this approach be used for images or pdf? Inside the map task, I want process individual files in their entirety i.e. process each image in the input split separately.

I'm aware of the small files problem, and it will not be an issue for my case.

I want to use CombineFileInputFormat for the benefits of avoiding Mapper task setup/cleanup overhead, and data-locality preservation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process images in Hadoop, I can only recommend using [HIPI](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/), which should allow you to do what you need.

Otherwise, when you say you want to process individual files in their entirety, I don't think you can do this with conventional input formats, because even with `CombineFileInputFormat`, you would have no guarantee that what's in your split is exactly 1 image.

An approach you could also consider is to have in input a file containing URLs/locations of your images (for example you could put them in Amazon S3), and make sure you have as many mappers as images, and then each map task would be able to process an individual image. I've done something similar not so long ago and it worked ok.

Comment: Sorry, If I was not clear. I want to use `CombineFileInputFormat` for feeding each mapper with multiple images, so an input split having more than 1 image is expected. Will it be possible to find the boundaries of individual images within the mapper? Also, is it possible that `CombineFileInputFormat` will split a single image accross two input splits?

Comment: The reason I wanted to avoid HIPI is that the images are managed by an external server (Fedora Commons) that uses HDFS as its file storage. So, I would have to create copies of the original images in HIPI archive. It would increase the storage requirements of the cluster. Also, I would have to rebuild HIPI archive, when images are added/removed. 

I aslo considered the other solution of using the list of URLs as input, but the data locality advantage will be lost.