# Hadoop: How to get each file path in CombineFileInputFormat?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have many files, some of which are very small. In order to reduce number of mappers, I'd like to use CombineFileInputFormat. 
The file name will be used as part of the key of the mapper output.

I have tried some methods as follows to get the file name of each chunk in CombineFileSplit, but all failed.

1) I see `conf.set("map.input.file", split.getPath(idx).toString());` in the function

`initNextRecordReader()` of class `CombineFileRecordReader`. But `NullPointerException`

happens in my `map()` function, as `context.getConfiguration().get("map.input.file")`

returns `null`.

2) I also try `((FileSplit) (context.getInputSplit())).getPath().getName()` in mapper, 
but `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileSplit cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit` happens.

**So how do I get each file name in the CombineFileSplit ?**

============================================================

**The input files are lzo compressed, and they are not indexed for now.**

The following is my codes:

I implement CombineFileInputFormat like this:

```
public class CombinedInputFormat extends CombineFileInputFormat<LongWritable, Text> {

    @Override
    public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit arg0,
            TaskAttemptContext arg1) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new CombineFileRecordReader<LongWritable, Text>((CombineFileSplit) arg0, arg1, CombineLzoLineRecordReader.class);
    }

}
```

and this is CombineLzoLineRecordReader that extends LzoLineRecordReader:

```
public class CombineLzoLineRecordReader extends LzoLineRecordReader {
    private int index;

    public CombineLzoLineRecordReader(CombineFileSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context, Integer index)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public void initialize(InputSplit genericSplit, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        CombineFileSplit combineSplit = (CombineFileSplit) genericSplit;
        FileSplit fileSplit = new FileSplit(combineSplit.getPath(index), combineSplit.getOffset(index), combineSplit.getLength(index), combineSplit.getLocations());
        super.initialize(fileSplit, context);
    }
}
```

And my map methods is like this :

```
private String getName(String filePath) {
        String[] filePathDir = filePath.split("/");
        return filePathDir[filePathDir.length - 1];
    }

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String name = getName(context.getConfiguration().get("map.input.file"));

        line = new String(value.getBytes(), 0, value.getLength(), "ISO-8859-1");
        lineFields = line.split("\t",-1);
        if (lineFields != null && lineFields.length >= 20) { 
                    // do something ...
        }
    }
```

And error infomation :

```
13/06/14 17:02:50 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201209101415_762760_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.netease.devilfish.hadoop.job.LogAnalysisDailyMapper.getName(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you check your codes? I use `context.getConfiguration().get("map.input.file")` in the `map` method, and I can get the path. You can paste the codes of setting up job to help us find if any configuration is error.

Comment: Yep. I have tried it several times. Do you also use CombineFileInputFormat ? See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1743 . By the way, my hadoop version is 0.20.2-cdh3u2.

Comment: Are you querying the value of `map.input.file` in the setup method of your mapper, or the map method? Can you post some code as to how you're extending the abstract `CombineFileInputFormat` class to create the record reader

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have updated the question description. Would you please help me find out the incorrect point ?

Comment: How do you set up the job? I use `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileInputFormat`. Do you use MultipleInputs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730754/how-to-use-combinefileinputformat-for-java-in-hadoop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CombineFileRecordReader sets the input path in the task context and not the mapper context. They are two different context objects and hence the first error. I have been facing this same issue and this is how I solved it

Since both CombineLzoLineRecordReader and mapper class will run in same jvm, you can share the data through static variables. Modify the CombineLzoLineRecordReader class as following (changes in asterisks)

```
public class CombineLzoLineRecordReader extends LzoLineRecordReader {
    private int index;
    **private static String currentPath**;

    public CombineLzoLineRecordReader(CombineFileSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context, Integer index)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public void initialize(InputSplit genericSplit, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        CombineFileSplit combineSplit = (CombineFileSplit) genericSplit;
        FileSplit fileSplit = new FileSplit(combineSplit.getPath(index), combineSplit.getOffset(index), combineSplit.getLength(index), combineSplit.getLocations());
        **currentPath = fileSplit.getPath().toString();**
        super.initialize(fileSplit, context);
    }

    public static String getCurrentFilePath() {
        return currentFilePath;
    }
}
```

Use CombineLzoLineRecordReader.getCurrentFilePath() in your mapper code to get the file path.